# Can't SSH into Gitlab

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, openssh

I have a gitlab ce image running via docker-compose

```
gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://gitlab.theboohers.org'
        # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
      - '8001:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      - app-network
```

I can login via https, (using nginx proxy), but I can't authenticate via ssh.

I verified that port 22 is listening:

```
nc -vz gitlab.theboohers.org 22
Connection to gitlab.theboohers.org (194.195.222.5) 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

In the verbose output, I see that the key is being offered: `debug1: Offering public key: /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256`

But I'm met with the error:
`git@gitlab.theboohers.org: Permission denied (publickey).`

Full verbose ssh connection at: https://gist.github.com/tbbooher/336e1bb277456efde6003111a56f3118

Comment: Do you use the same port to SSH into the host machine? It could be that your key is only in the container `authorized_keys` (because you added it via the webui) but not on the actual host. I would suggest you use a different port for host machine SSH and gitlab SSH.

Comment: I'll check. They may be the problem.

Comment: You were spot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to connect with ssh, I had to add the following lines in the GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG environment variable :

```yaml
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://${GITLAB_HOST}'
        # ...
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = ${SSH_PORT}
```

and to open the port (as you have) :

```yaml
    ports:
      - ${SSH_PORT}:22
```

After that, i was able to clone repositories with urls like :

```sh
git clone ssh://git@${GITLAB_HOST}:${SSH_PORT}/${REPOSITORY}.git
```

Note that the port 22 was already used and I had to set another one.

Comment: BTW, what is up with the ${VARIABLE} names -- i use $VARIABLE

Comment: @bonhoffer In this case, it shouldn't matter. However, image you had an env variable `SSH=FOO` and one `SSH_PORT=22`. Then `$SSH_PORT` would result in `FOO_PORT`, and `${SSH_PORT}` would give `22`.