# Gitlab ssh connection timeout (with Cloudflare and Client crt)

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I can't connect to my gitlab server. The webUI is secured with Cludflare and Client cert. But that should not really matter because I want to connect with ssh

ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.domain

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/userdir/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/userdir/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for gitlab.domain
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/userdir/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/userdir/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "gitlab.domain" port 12345
debug3: resolve_host: lookup gitlab.domain:12345
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.domain [123.123.123.123] port 12345.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address 123.123.123.123 port 12345: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.domain [123.123.123.123] port 12345.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
```

~/.ssh/config

```
Host gitlab.domain
  HostName gitlab.domain
  User gitlabuser
  Port 12345
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git
```

(The key is stored in the corresponding account)

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Connectivity problem. Not related to Git at all.

Comment: `tcptraceroute -p 12345 gitlab.domain` (or `mtr` or any similar tool to trace where packets stop).

Comment: Ok, the domain does not seem to be resolved by Cloudflare? ```traceroute to gitlab.domain (172.67.171.171)``` IP Info ```name:"Cloudflare, Inc.",```

Comment: Do I have to take a port that is supported by Cloudflare?
It is actually only the domain that is resolved, right?

Comment: Oh man, my mistake. The IP from CLoudflare looks amazingly similar to the one from my server : Cloudflare: 104.21.55.165 / My : 104.000.000.165

Answer (score 0):

As long as a curl -v telnet://gitlab.domain:12345 shows you a timeout, that means:

- either the network route is not opened between your machine and gitlab.domain:12345
- or gitlab.domain does not listen on port 12345

Double-check your [GitLab ssh port configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67939638/6309) and make sure it is up and running, using the port you need.

Comment: The config is correct so far, can it be that I have to take a port that Cloudflare supports?

Comment: @Kekx Do you mean the curl command returns a "Connected" message?

Comment: No, the domain is not resolved by CLoudflare ```Immediate connect fail for 2606:4700:3035::6815:37a5: Network is unreachable``` , but I have as ssh port one that is not supported by CLoudflare, can it be because of that